# Python Regex stops after first "|" match

Tags: python, regex

```
p = re.compile("[AG].{2}[ATG|ATA|AAG].{1}G")
regex_result = p.search('ZZZAXXATGXGZZZ')
regex_result.group()
'AXXATG'
```

I was expecting `AXXATGXG` instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a grouping construct `(...)` rather than a character class `[...]` around the alternatives:

```
p = re.compile("[AG].{2}(?:ATG|ATA|AAG).G")
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `(?:ATG|ATA|AAG)` matches 3 sequences: either a `ATG`, or `ATA` or `AAG`. The `[ATG|ATA|AAG]` character class matches 1 char, either `A`, `T`, `G` or `|`.

Note the `{1}` is redundant and can be removed.

Python:

```
import re
p = re.compile("[AG].{2}(?:ATG|ATA|AAG).G")
regex_result = p.search('ZZZAXXATGXGZZZ')
print(regex_result.group())
# => AXXATGXG
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/reDEND)

Comment: Beautiful explanation. You saved my day!